# Run a test method team.accessLogs in Slack of a specific user

Tags: methods, slack, slack-api

Is there a way to run a [team.accessLogs](https://api.slack.com/methods/team.accessLogs) method to a specific user? I tried adding an 'extra args' with a user_id, username, and other formats but not working. I'm a slack admin, on a standard (paid) workspace.

Checking it via [workspacename]slack.com/account/logs, is not an option for me, as this needs to be checked from the back end.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. You will get the logs for all users with this method, so you can just filter out the user you need?

Comment: Thanks for responding Erik, team.accessLogs shows all the users' logs, we have like thousands of users who are in slack who logs in and out everyday, and it's hard for me to check that logs for a particular user only